# Formula to calculate mining earnings (PPLNS/PPS)

Tags: hashrate

I'm looking for a formula to calculate my pool earnings (PPLNS pool) like [this website](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr)... Their calculation is based on:

- network hashrate
- pool hashrate
- exchange rate (1XMR = ~130$)
- fixed block reward
- block time

and obviously:

- hashrateobviously
- power consumption (W)
- power cost
- pool fee

So is there is a function to calculate my monero earnings in a PPLNS pool? (and PPS also but not so important to me...)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate earnings specifically for PPS or for PPLNS is pointless as the divergence is based on how often the pool find a block. If you are trying to find an average, then both payment methods equals.

So the formula you found is the best you may have to estimate your earnings.

If you want to calculate the expected earnings from a past day where you know the time window (the N * blocktime from PPLNS) and the number of block found you have to calculate earning from each block based on your average hashrate divided by the average pool hashrate on the same time window.

A basic formula would be ((your hashrate) / (the network hashrate)) * (720 blocks per day) * (block reward) = XMR/day then - (wattage cost per day)

Comment: And how is the page calculating the earnings? At least the average earnings... Could you please add a formula to calculate the average earnings?

Comment: ((your hashrate) / (the network hashrate)) * (720 blocks per day) * (block reward) = XMR/day then - (wattage cost per day)

Comment: OK it's much clearer now. Why 720 blocks per day? How can I calculate the blocks per day?

Comment: 720 blocks per day because a target blocktime of 2 minutes and 1440 minutes per day. There are 720 new blocks added each day to the blockchain.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good formula! Getting similar results like cryptocompare.com... Thank you!

Comment: I'm suggesting an edit to include the formula into your answer...

Comment: Edited with the formula